# Redirect old google php listed links to go to new .NET site

Tags: php, redirect

I've created a new website in .NET replacing a previous php website. I've updated the xml sitemap and 404 error pages but would like the user to be directed to the homepage when the user clicks on a php page listed in a google just now. At the minute it displays No input file specified on the page when you click on the google link.

Thanks for your help